# If look up value MATCH, then look up in the another cell of the last matched value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I've been seriously struggling with this for a couple days so I need help :(

Let's assume I have the following data with the following columns A:`ID`, B: `Felony`, C: `Recidivism` and D: `Same felony?`. It looks as this table:

| Row | ID | Felony | Recidivism? | Same felony? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MX1902 | Steal | No | No |
| 2 | MX1903 | Steal | No | No |
| 3 | MX1901 | Kidnapping | No | No |
| 4 | MX1902 | Steak | Yes | Yes |

What I have been trying to do, is to identify if the column A (`ID`) value match with **previous** column cells. If TRUE, then look in the most recent match row, and identify if the value of cell in the column B (`Felony`) (from that same matched row) is the same that the actual row. For this example, I've been looking to place the formula on **D4**.

Do you guys have any idea of how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,$B2)>1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

The trick is that $A$2:$A2 will expand to $A$2:$A3 etc as the formula is copied down, always ending on the row of the formula (starting in row 2, of course). Therefore the result should always be at least 1, since the current row is included in the count. If the result is higher there is a repetition and the IF function returns *True*.

Actually, `COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,$B2)` returns the number of of offenses and `COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,$B2)-1` therefore is the number of ***previous*** offenses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2010, you can use Aggregate to find the most recent previous offence and compare it with the current offence:

```
=IF(C2="No","No",IF(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A$1:A1)/(A$1:A1=A2),1))=B2,"Yes","No"))
```

Countifs as suggested by @Variatus is a good way to find if there *was* a previous offence - I actually used Match as an alternative:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,A$1:A1,0)),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

This would give "no" because although there was a previous incident of "Steal", the most recent offence was kidnapping:

[image]